Error using ffmpeg to convert flv video
I am trying to convert flv video to mp4 using ffmpeg.
I have checked questions about converting from flv like this one and this one but it didn't help.
Commands I have executed:
ffmpeg -i input.flv -c:v libx264 output.mp4

also:
ffmpeg -i input.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -strict experimental output.mp4

also:
ffmpeg -i input.flv -codec copy output.mp4

also:
ffmpeg -i input.flv -c copy -copyts output.mp4

also:
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis output.mp4

also:
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i input.flv -c:v libx264 output.mp4

I get below error from all above variants:

[flv @ 0xaaab0f4ec060] Packet mismatch 1703445535 198421 198574


[flv @0xaaab0f4ec060] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video:
h264, none): unspecified size Consider increasing the value for the
'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options


Input #0, flv, from 'input.flv':   Duration: 00:00:07.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate:
16070 kb/s   Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 1k tbr, 1k tbn


Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4': Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Please note that I cannot reproduce the video using vlc. I managed to reproduce the video after downloading FLV-Media-Player
I think my video needs some kind of pre-processing but have no idea how to go about this.
UPDATE:
Using MediaInfoOnline tool to process my flv video I got below information (no errors reported from the tool):
General
Complete name                            : input.flv
Format                                   : Flash Video
File size                                : 12.2 MiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : 7
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 16.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Standard                                 : NTSC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Color range                              : Full
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709


You could try ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i input.flv -c:v libx264 output.mp4 which might work out here ??

@Prem I have tried this as well. Same result.

(1) You could try online tools like https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline to check what is wrong with the media. (2) You could try to make the FLV Player make a copy with minor modifications , where the error may get automatically rectified,

@Prem Can you please check the edit I made? I guess my linux box is missing the codec of the file?

(0) All looks okay there. (1) You could try some other flv file , even downloading some new flv file , to check whether that will get converted. (2) If yes , then input.flv is the culprit. If not , then likely your system is missing some necessary library file for the codec. (3) You could try loading input.flv into vlc to check the media info & the codec info & the error log.

@Prem I have tried converting the flv file using 4 different online converters. None of them worked. But MediaInfoOnline tool didn't find anything wrong with the file.

It is then definitely confirmed that your media file is faulty. It is not related to ffmpeg. You could try converting with handbrake tool.

@Prem Handbrake also fails to open the file. I get the message: No valid source or titles found

Best Course Of Action : [[1]] you could try to make flv player save a copy with minor modifications ( size , quality , volume , some thing else ) where that copy will not have the error , hence you can convert that later. [[2]] you could record the output of flv player to make a new media file.

I finally managed to get a working solution. I first installed flvmeta
$ git clone https://github.com/noirotm/flvmeta.git
$ cd flvmeta
$ cmake .
$ make
$ sudo make install

I then executed following command:
$ flvmeta -t -f input.flv output_meta.flv

After this, following command works as expected:
$ ffmpeg -i output_meta.flv -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -strict experimental output.mp4

